# Geometric interpretation of alternating bilinear forms as an oriented area

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

Till very recently I believed to understand what is written in the Wikipedia entry on the exterior algebra: *The bivector $u\wedge v$ represents the plane spanned by the vectors, "weighted" with a number, given by the area of the oriented parallelogram with sides $u$ and $v$.*

But now I have doubts: In $\mathbb R^3$ the natural two-dimensional Hausdorff measure of the (non-oriented) parallelogramm $p(u,v)$ with sides $u$ and $v$ is not bilinear: If $u,v,w$ are the edges of a cube (say, the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$) then $p(u,v)$ and $p(u,w)$ are squares
(sides of the cube) of area ($2$-dimensional Hausdorff measure) $1$ but $p(u,v+w)$ is a rectangle inside the cube of area $\sqrt{2}$. This does not seem to be issue of orientation.
(In $\mathbb R^2$ the geometric interpretation of bivectors seems plausible because of shearing.)
What do I missunderstand?

Comment: Good spot! This interpretation only works for top-dimensional forms. (An easier example are one-forms in $\Reals^2$ which should measure the length. But they don't as $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is not bilinear).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, Pawel. Is there a simple geometric interpretation of two-forms in $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: Well, I will give an infinitesimal heuristics. Take any (smooth) surface $M\subset \mathbb R^3$ and a point $p\in M$. Then locally $M$ looks like a plane $T_pM$. In this plane a two-form measures the area of infinitesimal parallelograms in this plane, and is hence bilinear. (This is a heuristics, but useful – you approximate a surface locally at each point by something you can measure and integrate these infinitesimal parts).

Comment: I would say that a bivector is "weighted" with an area in the same sens in which a vector is "wighted" with a length. You are not bothered by the fact that the length of the sum of two vectors is not always equal to the sum of their lengths, aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

I believe now that the point is that (at least some) alternating bilinear forms do not measure the area of an oriented parallelogram but *the AREA OF A SHADOW of the parallelogram:*

If $(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ is a basis of the vector space we have the dual basis $(b_1^*,\ldots,b_n^*)$ in $X^*$ (so that $b_j^*(b_k)=\delta_{j,k}$).
Then $b_j^* \wedge b_k^*$ should measure an oriented area of *the projection* (or the shadow) of an oriented parallelogramm into the plane spanned by $b_j,b_k$ (of course, the projection does not only depend on $b_j$ and $b_k$ but on the whole basis -- in the presence of a scalar product the orthogonal projection is a kind of canonical choice).

If one defines an *oriented area in a plane* by homogeneity in each component and the shearing property (i.e., the areas of the parallelogramms spanned by $(x,y)$, $(x+y,y)$ and $(x,y+x)$ are the same) one can prove alternating bilinearity and uniqueness up to constant factors. Because the projection is linear this implies the bilinearity of $b_j^*\wedge b_k^*$.

Hence $b_j^*\wedge b_k^*$ is determined by alternating bilinearity, by $b_j^*\wedge b_k^*(x,y)=b_j^*\wedge b_k^*(\pi(x),\pi(y))$ where $\pi$ is the projection, and the norming condition $b_j^*\wedge b_k^*(b_j,b_k)=1$.